# delete outlook all stuck read receipts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Recently, I restored my desktop to factory settings. After restoring, I downloaded all email to Outlook 2007.

All of the mail was marked as unread, but they were old, so I marked them as read. After this, Outlook was stuck in `sending read receipts`.

I found Microsoft Exchange Server Information Store Viewer (MDBVU32) to remove these. However, I still have a large number of pending read receipts in Outlook that I can't remove with this tool all in one shot - I have to do the complete process for every single read receipt.

Is there a way to remove these pending receipts in bulk?

Comment: You could try [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/)